# awk + how to convert CSV names to one field names

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, perl, csv

I have the following csv file

```
more names.csv


erik kastelo , roman flot , david krish , timoty klon 
derek matue , jenfaer loper , kris dovalo 
sara paula , boris miue , kami san-toto , benjaman hurato , lim paulo
.
.
.
```

so I want to convert this csv file to the following example format

please advice how to do it with awk , or perl one liner or else

```
erik kastelo 
roman flot 
david krish
timoty klon 
derek matue 
jenfaer loper 
kris dovalo 
sara paula 
boris miue 
kami san-toto 
benjaman hurato  
lim paulo
```

Comment: `sed` stream editing is the tool you're looking for.  If you use `awk` you'll need to pipe to another util to complete the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F ' *, *' -v OFS='\n' '{ NF=NF } 1' file.csv
```

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/ *, */\n/g' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F'/\h*,\h*/' -lpe '$_ = join $\, @F' yourcsvfile
```

In case you're concerned about trailing blanks, then augment by 1 more step:

```
perl -F'/\h*,\h*/' -lpe '$_ = join $\, @F;s/\h+$//'  yourcsvfile
```

Comment: any reason to use `join`? why not a simpler `perl -pe 's/\h*,\h*/\n/g'`?

Comment: not work for me , its give empty output

Comment: @Sundeep You are right!. That's much cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: @yael You may use this: `perl -lpe 's/\s*,\s*/\n/g' yourcsvfile` as maybe your Perl doesn't recognise the `\h`